# Can we access multiple accounts using Scatter at once?

Tags: scatter

I want to access all the identities present in my scatter wallet at once so that I can have all the accounts and the balance in them. But, I think, we can use only one identity at a time as we have select the identity first.
So, is there a way so that I can have information of all the accounts present in my wallet at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [Scatter Desktop wallet](https://github.com/GetScatter/ScatterDesktop), you can view a list of all of your Blockchain Accounts, and then view the your staked cpu/net, and remaining RAM, by clicking on the "Account" you want to view the details of. Your Identities are stored separately from your blockchain accounts.

Here's an example of having multiple Accounts, with one account selected to view its details...

[image]

Comment: Currently, I am using scatter Chrome extension but when I start the application, scatter asks to me select one identity and after I get to access only one account. So, how can i have the information about all the identities?

Comment: Chrome extension - you can only use one account at a time. FYI,  Chrome extension development is going to be security bug-fix only going forward so time for getting used to desktop version!

Comment: ok, I will have to try the desktop version then.